# What does checkbox do for QField?

Tags: qfield

I'm creating forms for collecting data using QField. To the right of all the widgets there's a checkbox. From what I can tell it doesnt do anything.
I can leave it unchecked or check it but it makes no difference to the data I'm collecting.

What does the checkbox do for QField?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have not used QField since a few years but in the docs they write:

> **Remember attribute values** 
> For quick collection of rather homogeneus [sic!] datasets, it is crucial to not having to enter the same attribute values over an over. The checkboxes at the right of every attribute allow remembering each attribute individually so that the next time you will add a feature on the same layer, these attributes will be automatically pre-filled.

https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/digitize